# How to block specific email address?

Tags: customer, blocks, email, guest, fraud

How to block specific email address? The customer is registered as guest but making series of suspected fraudulent transactions. We see he is using different credit cards, fictitious address and different IP address. The only info he doesn't change are his name and email address.

Comment: You can use this extension - https://github.com/magekey/module-customer-restriction

Comment: you can check this extension : https://magecomp.com/magento-2-restrict-fake-registration.html

Answer (score 0):

Via Magento, you log in your Magento Admin account and navigate to:

Customers / All customers. Then, you select the desired customer and edit as per your necessity.

[image]

Via CPanel, you may block his IP or email address. Accessing Visitors and Security sections as below:

[image]
[image]

Please note that you may block a sequence of IPs. That is the way I usually protect my website from suspected IPs. You may search for "where is this IP" on Google and follow the steps to identify if that country is part of your business.

Hope that helps